# How should I write math?

Tags: math-mode, best-practices

I'm new to TeX and I  would like to use it to write math (on a Mac). I've just downloaded [MacTex](https://tug.org/mactex/) and I'm wondering what's the recommended workflow. Am I supposed to write math in TeX macros/code and perhaps get used and "see" through the TeX macros? Or should I use a wysiwyg editor ?

I'm also wondering how mathematicians do math on a computer even if they have no intention to publish their work.

Comment: most people just write the tex macros directly, it's far more reliable and quicker than trying to edit in a displayed math layout.

Comment: There is no real wysiwyg editor for (La)TeX; [lyx](http://www.lyx.org/) tries to come close to being wysiwyg, but depending on the type of math material you need to get typeset, you may be better off simply learning how to typeset the math material using LaTeX and dedicated packages such as [amsmath](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) and [mathtools](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools). Even if it's mostly math you're going to typeset, you should still make an effort to become familiar with the basics of LaTeX, e.g., by working through the [Short Introduction to LaTeX2e](http://ctan.org/pkg/lshort).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  they basically they "never" see / use the rendered document, right?

Comment: I think real mathematicians use paper and pencil only. At the very end when they finished, they give the papers to the undergraduate students to type it in using Latex.

Comment: I don't understand your comment sorry, who do you mean by "they" there?

Comment: We cannot tell you what you are supposed to do and what you should use. Maybe you can add the worries you have with writing math with (La)TeX macros (which is most likely the superior way to write math in (La)TeX): Special aligning? Special functions? Big (in size) functions?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I mean "most people". Responding to ``most people just write the tex macros directly...``

Comment: @Nasser I suspected that might be the case but I thought things changed... As far as I understand TeX is used only to digitalise hand written math but mathematicians don't do math using TeX.

Comment: @themihai I meant most TeX users of course, but yes editing the source and looking at the rendered output are normally distinct activities.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I'm new to math and I'm trying to learn on a computer rather than using paper and pencil thus the reason why I asked what's the best practice. Even if no one can tell you what to do it's good to ask advice.

Comment: @Nasser That's a damned shame, shunting that meaningless work off to your students. Aside, insofar as prose goes, I do that writing with directly on the computer. I've often done real mathematics directly on the computer, too, but it is easier with a whiteboard for some things. (I've never published a pure maths paper.) OP, this is an inherently opinion-based question. Either ask in chat (we're nice!) or [ask on reddit](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/6000/17423) (perhaps less nice, sometimes). There isn't a correct answer for this question. I've seen it done well both ways.